# How to check if a firebase document has a field with value?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am busy learning Angular + Firebase and I came across a problem.  I have a collection of users and one of roles.  I am using the ID generated for the users to store my role data.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: Firebase snapshot]

I want to use the canActivate function to manage who can edit what data.  How do you check if a user has the admin field set to true?  I can get the roles document for the user with this:

```
this.afs.collection('roles').doc(id).valueChanges()
```

I can display the data in HTML like this:

```
*ngIf="roles$ | async as roles"
```

However, I want to use it to verify if the user has admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the `take(1)` or `first()` operator to only get the first emit from the firebase stream. The `CanActivate` guard expects a completing `Observable`:

```
export interface UserRoles {
  admin: boolean;
  editor: boolean;
  subscriber: boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IsAdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user.pipe(
      switchMap((user) => !user?.uid
        ? of(false)
        : this.afs.doc<UserRoles>(`roles/${user.uid}`).valueChanges().pipe(
            map((roles) => !!(roles?.admin))
          )
      ),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I implement this, I get the following error:

Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: I have a follow up question.  The code can block unwanted users, but how do I redirect them if the boolean is false?

Comment: @user1303840 you return an `Observable<UrlTree[]>` which you can create by injecting the router in your guard and using the `router.createUrlTree` method, which takes sort of the same parameters as the `navigate` method